# How to connect to TERADATA using ODBC API

Tags: odbc, teradata

I was building a Teradata connector using ODBC API with C, C++.

It's odbc.ini file.

```
[ODBC]
# For Data Direct to load its error messages
# Data Direct Driver Manager looks for the messages here:
# "/opt/teradata/client/16.20/locale/xx_xx/LC_MESSAGES/"
InstallDir=/opt/teradata/client/16.20
Trace=no
TraceDll=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/odbctrac.so
TraceFile=/home/lkw/teradatatrace.log
TraceAutoStop=0

[ODBC Data Sources]
teradata1620=tdata.so

[teradata1620]
Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib/tdata.so
DBCName=192.168.4.118
Username=dbc
Password=dbc
Database=dbc
```

It's part of Source Code.

```
int Todbc1620::Connect(string userId, string password, string instance)
{
  SQLRETURN wReturn;
  char wConnStr[1024];

  mUserId = userId;
  mPassword = password;
  mInstance = instance;
  /* Connect to database server */

  wReturn = TODBC1620_SQLConnect(mDbc,
        (SQLCHAR*)mInstance.c_str(),
        strlen(mInstance.c_str()),
        (SQLCHAR*)mUserId.c_str(), 
        strlen(mUserId.c_str()),
        (SQLCHAR*)mPassword.c_str(),
        strlen(mPassword.c_str()));

  if( wReturn != SQL_SUCCESS)
  {
    Diagnostics('E', wReturn);
    SetStatus( NOT_CONNECTED );
    return FUNC_FAIL;
  }

  SetStatus( CONNECTED );

  return FUNC_SUCCESS;
}
```

txodbc64 and isql also operate normally.

```
[lkw@localhost Source]$ isql -v teradata1620
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| echo [string]                         |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> ^C


[lkw@localhost bin]$ tdxodbc64

Enter Data Source Name: teradata1620
Enter UserID: dbc
Enter Password:

Connecting with SQLConnect(DSN=teradata1620,UID=dbc,PWD=*)...

.....ODBC connection successful.

ODBC version        = -03.52.0000-
DBMS name           = -Teradata-
DBMS version        = -16.20.3223  16.20.32.23-
Driver name         = -tdataodbc_sb64.so-
Driver version      = -16.20.00.127-
Driver ODBC version = -03.52-

(type quit to terminate adhoc)
Enter SQL string : ^C
```

However, SQLConnect() created using the ODBC API is returning -1.

The error message is as follows.

```
[DBAPI-E0801] Teradata Error
[Teradata][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString
function: [Teradata][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve
the error message for key 'LibsLoadErr' with message parameters ['""']
and component ID 3: Message not found in file
"/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib/../odbc_64/ErrorMessages/en-US/ODBCMessages.xml"
```

What should I do?

I have a doubt, but for what purpose does the teradata.teradataodbc.ini file exist in the /opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64 subdirectory?

Comment: I found a solution to this case.

You have to add the ODBCInstLib option to your $TERADATA_HOME/lib64/teradata.teradataodbc.ini file like this.

ODBCInstLib=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/lib64/libodbcinst.so

(My path of TERADATA_HOME is /opt/teradata/client/16.20)